Data on Helicopter Moment of Inertia
I am looking for some data on real helicopters.
Specifically, something that is very hard to find is the moment of inertia of the main rotor.
I found the following:

CH-53 https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/19810003557
OH-58A https://digitalcommons.usf.edu/etd/1921/

I tried some flight handbooks and user manuals but with no success. I was also looking for rotor blade masses to estimate the MOI with. That also brought no success. Even ChatGPT was absolutely lost on this one. Mails to manufacturers where also sent a while ago, with no replies thus far.
Do you guys have any idea where I could find such data? One or two more helicopters would suffice for my cause.
Thanks!
PS: Is this some kind of extreme secret I am looking for here? Is it such a sensitive parameter? Or is it rather the opposite and "usually not interesting"? I have a hard time believing the latter because quite a few formulae need the Rotor Moment of Inertia for basic helicopter calculations.

Hi, Resource (including data) location, is off topic here. Take a look at [help/on-topic] for more info.

You are right to assume that it is a property which is well known by the manufacturer and also needed for a lot of modelling and simulation work. However, as all industries, the manufacturers are quite secretive about these kind of numbers and why wouldn't they be, after all you could be a competitor looking to gain an advantage.
Without contacts into the industry and an NDA, I doubt you will get the exact number, BUT you could try to estimate. Simply make a couple of informed assumptions about where the main masses sits, and you should arrive at reasonable numbers. Good luck!

You can estimate the weight using the last chapters of Johnson (pdf). Chapter 29.2 should be the right one

@sophit thanks for your reply. The problem is that I am building a model for estimating it and to verify that my estimates are good (enough) I would need real data. I am aware of the work you sent by Johson, however, they only estimate weights and not weight distribution in the blade, making an estimate for MOI hard.

Blade's structure is quite homogeneous along the span, you can simply consider the weight as being linearly distributed too.
